# A way to remove specific cookie from HttpRequestHeaders in WebApi

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to remove specific `Set-Cookie` header from `HttpResponseHeaders` in `OnActionExecuted` method of `ActionFilter`.

I'm having few issues with that:

1. I cannot see the way of enumerate headers. The collection is always
   empty, even if I see headers in debugger.
2. Because I cannot
   enumerate, I cannot remove specific header. I can only remove all
   headers with the same key, but `Set-Cookie` can have multiple
   entries.

Currently I'm removing all cookies, but this is not what I want.

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
{                
   HttpResponseHeaders headers = actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers;
   IEnumerable<string> values;
   if (headers.TryGetValues("Set-Cookie", out values))
   {
       actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.Remove("Set-Cookie");
   }

   base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
}
```

Comment: have you get solution of this issue?

Comment: @KalpeshBoghara only by workaround. Add context item in filter for specific action `OnActionExecuting` `HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("RemoveAuthCookieKey", true);`. And then in Global.asax in `Application_EndRequest` if key exists `this.Response.Cookies.Remove(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);`

Answer (score 5):

From the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178195.aspx):

> You cannot directly delete a cookie on a user's computer. However, you can direct the user's browser to delete the cookie by setting the cookie's expiration date to a past date. The next time a user makes a request to a page within the domain or path that set the cookie, the browser will determine that the cookie has expired and remove it.

So, how to remove/delete cookie in ASP.NET Web Api at action filter level, just try to set expiration date of cookie to a past date:

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
{
    var response = actionExecutedContext.Response;
    var request = actionExecutedContext.Request;

    var currentCookie = request.Headers.GetCookies("yourCookieName").FirstOrDefault();
    if (currentCookie != null)
    {
        var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("yourCookieName", "")
        {
            Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(-1),
            Domain = currentCookie.Domain,
            Path = currentCookie.Path
        };

        response.Headers.AddCookies(new[] { cookie });
    }

    base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
}
```

Comment: I don't want to delete cookie on user computer. I just don't want to send cookie back to user in Web-Api, to prevent sliding expiration on some web-api actions. So I want to remove specific Set-Cookie header.

Comment: Ok, then I am just curious why you have to do this @Marcin?

Comment: I have web app with internal usage of web api. It is used for simplify request, and get responsibility about returned format to javascript, etc. Because I'm using forms authentication, the cookie is sent after some time, to extend expiration time. There is few actions in my app, which are called in background, automatically. So I want to prevent them to extend expiration of Auth cookie.